# Staying on the same page with python requests in order to solve captcha

Tags: python, python-requests, captcha

I want to use python requests to get a page, decode its captcha, and then post to the same page without refreshing.

I currently have

```
page = session.get("captchapage.com")
captcha_string = decode_captcha_from_contents(page.content)
session.post("captchapage.com", data = {"captcha": captcha_string})
```

however, the problem is that session.post goes to the website again instead of staying on the same page, which results in a new captcha.